# Initially mallocate 0 elements to later reallocate and measure size

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I have a function that will add a new position to an array by reallocating new memory every time it is called.

The problem is that, for each call I need it to add one position to the array, starting from 1 at first call, but I understand that I have to mallocate before reallocating.

So my question is, can I initially do something like `p = malloc(0)` and then reallocate for example using `p = (int *)realloc(p,sizeof(int))` inside my function? `p` is declared as `int *p`.

Maybe with a different syntax?

Of course I could make a condition in my function that would mallocate if memory hasn't been allocated before and reallocate if it has, but I am looking for a better way.

And the second problem I have is... Once reallocated more positions, I want to know the size of the array.

I know that if, for example, I declare an array `a[10]`, the number of elements would be defined by `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`, but for some reason that doesn't work with arrays declared as pointers and then reallocated.

Any advice?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY either one is OK

Comment: @BLUEPIXY there's no bet, they both work

Comment: That's a very bad `realloc` example, 1. Don't cast `void *`, 2. Don't overwrite the pointer before you check for `null`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `realloc` can be used with any pointer prevoiusly returned by `malloc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could initialize your pointer to `NULL`, so that the first time you call `realloc(yourPointer, yourSize)`, it will return the same value as `malloc(yourSize)`.

For your second problem, you could use a struct that contains your pointer and a `count` member.

```
struct MyIntVector {
    int * ptr;
    size_t count;
}
```

Then you probably will want to define wrapper functions for malloc, realloc, and free (where you could reset `ptr` to NULL), that takes your struct as one of the parameters, and updates the struct as needed.

If you want to optimize this for pushing 1 element at a time, you could add a `allocatedCount` member, and only realloc if `count == allocatedCount`, with a new `allocatedCount` equals (for example) twice the old `allocatedCount`.

You should implement this in a `MyIntVector_Push(MyIntVector *, int )` function.

You will then have a simplified c version of c++ `std::vector<int>` (but without automatic deallocation when the object goes out of scope).

Comment: please dont link to C++ resources. C and C++ are different (and maybe the resources)

Comment: @wildplasser noted, I removed the ressource.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer and thank you also for the alternatives you gave! I'll start studying all the possibilities immediatelly.

Answer (score 1):

As ThreeStarProgrammer57 said just use realloc.

```
realloc(NULL, nr_of_bytes) is equivalent to malloc(nr_of_bytes)
```

so

```
p = realloc(p, your_new_size)
```

will work just fine the first time if p is initialized to NULL. But be sure to pass the number of bytes you need after resizing, not the additional space that you want, as you have written your question.

As regarding the size, you have to keep track of it. That's the way C was designed.

Comment: For completeness: C11 (draft) 7.22.3.5/3 (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5p3)